# nginx auth_request: access original query parameter

Tags: authentication, nginx

I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to forward a query-parameter from the original URL to the `auth_request` handler/service?

Users should be able to add the API-token as a query-parameter like this:
`https://example.com/api/user?token=237263864823674238476`

And not via `header` or `cookie`. Can I access the `token` parameter somehow in the auth-service? Or write the `token` query-parameter in a custom header with NGINX?
Tried this so far:

```
location = /api/user {
  auth_request /auth;
  proxy_set_header X-auth-token-from-query $arg_token;

  proxy_pass http://<url>;
}
```

`/auth` endpoint doesn't get the `X-auth-token-from-query` header but after returning a `200` the upstream-proxy does get the header.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You'll very likely want to pass the url (the uri) to the auth-request endpoint as well. You can do this in one go:

```
location = /api/auth {
  proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
  proxy_set_header X-Original-METHOD $request_method;
  proxy_pass_request_body off;
  proxy_set_header Content-Length "";

  proxy_pass http://<url>;
}
```

Bonus: I also passed the method! :tada:

Answer (score 9):

The following worked for me

```
        location = /auth {
          internal;
          set $query '';
          if ($request_uri ~* "[^\?]+\?(.*)$") {
              set $query $1;
          }
          proxy_pass                http://myauthpoint?$query;
          proxy_pass_request_body   off;
          proxy_set_header          Content-Length "";
        }
```

Comment: This one is best, since the query params are nicely passed.  
I had to make a small edit so that the full original path is passed...  :
http://myauthpoint$uri?$query;

Answer (score 0):

My use case:

- I serve a reverse proxied API on `/api/`
- I have some other resource on `/protected` I want to secure using a check on `/api/auth-check` which requires passing a token query parameter

Inspired by the answer of user1955986 I parse `$request_uri`, but in stead of directly proxying it somewhere else I use it to set the `$args` parameter that gets passed on to the API endpoint:

```
location ^~ /api/ {
    ... your API config ...
}

location ^~ /protected/ {
    auth_request /auth-request;
    ... your protected resource config ...
}

location = /auth-request {
    internal;
    if ($request_uri ~* "[^\?]+\?(.*)$") {
        set $args $1;
    }
    rewrite ^.* /api/auth-check last;
}
```