# nginx auth_request using original uri

Tags: django, nginx, authorization

This may be related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36454011).

I try to provide static files using nginx. However, only registered users with the appropriate rights should be able to download these files.

Within the django application I can already authorize users, but since the downloads are not delivered by django, but by nginx, I had some problems with it.

Currently I have two locations within my nginx config.

```
location / {
    uwsgi_pass django;
    include    /usr/share/nginx/uwsgi_params;
}

location ~ /projects/(.*)/downloads/(.+[^/])$ {
    auth_request /api/auth;
    root /usr/share/nginx/downloads;
}
```

This configuration works, but I am unable to check if the registered user is allowed to access this download area.

It would be enough if I could adjust the second block to a syntax like this.

```
location ~ /projects/(.*)/downloads/(.+[^/])$ {
    auth_request /projects/$1/downloads/;
    root /usr/share/nginx/downloads;
}
```

But with this configuration not the uri is called, but the given string */projects/my_project/downloads/my_file.txt*

Is there a simple way to pass the original uri to an auth_request?

Thank you in advance

Comment: In your first example, did you try adding `location /api/auth` and set `proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;`? That would allow you to inspect that header in your code to check which resource is being accessed, no?

Comment: @dirkgroten You're right, all I had to do was add X-Original-URI. Then I could access it from django. Thank you very much